# Reduce lines of code without impacting performance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still learning Python (3.5) and I have this piece of code where it need to assign a lot of values to some objects, so I am wondering what is the most optimized way to do it. I am asking this because I lack of the knowledge to understand if "less lines of code" in a loop is more time-demanding than not using the loop (the file size is less, but the proccesing is increased... maybe?).

**Approach 1:**

```
    # 01
    self.lineReferencia1.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[16]))
    self.lineConcepto1.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[17]))
    self.lineCantidad1.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[18]))
    self.linePrecio1.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[19]))
    self.lineDescuento1.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[20]))
    # 02
    self.lineReferencia2.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[23]))
    self.lineConcepto2.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[24]))
    self.lineCantidad2.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[25]))
    self.linePrecio2.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[26]))
    self.lineDescuento2.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[27]))
    # 03
    self.lineReferencia3.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[30]))
    self.lineConcepto3.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[31]))
    self.lineCantidad3.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[32]))
    self.linePrecio3.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[33]))
    self.lineDescuento3.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[34]))
    # 04
    self.lineReferencia4.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[37]))
    self.lineConcepto4.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[38]))
    self.lineCantidad4.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[39]))
    self.linePrecio4.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[40]))
    self.lineDescuento4.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[41]))
```

**Approach 2:**

```
    items = (
    (self.lineReferencia1, registro[16]), (self.lineConcepto1, registro[17]), (self.lineCantidad1, registro[18]),
    (self.linePrecio1, registro[19]), (self.lineDescuento1, registro[20]), (self.lineReferencia2, registro[23]),
    (self.lineConcepto2, registro[24]), (self.lineCantidad2, registro[25]), (self.linePrecio2, registro[26]),
    (self.lineDescuento2, registro[27]), (self.lineReferencia3, registro[30]), (self.lineConcepto3, registro[31]),
    (self.lineCantidad3, registro[32]), (self.linePrecio3, registro[33]), (self.lineDescuento3, registro[34]),
    (self.lineReferencia4, registro[37]), (self.lineConcepto4, registro[38]), (self.lineCantidad4, registro[39]),
    (self.linePrecio4, registro[40]), (self.lineDescuento4, registro[41]))
    for i in items:
        i[0].setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(i[1]))
```

**Note:** With this approach, I reduce 20 lines of code into just 10, but the  real code doesn't have only 4 sections, it have 27, so the goal is to reduce 135 lines of code.

**Approach 3:**

Would the use of a dict to store the data, instead of a tuple of tuples would be more efficient in time of proccesing?

**Approach 4:**

Should I use method/function for each item instead of a loop?

**The real question:** Is there any other way to reduce lines of code on that file without impacting performance or readability? How? Why?

Comment: My immediate reaction: why have `variableName1`, `variableName2`, etc? Add them together in a data structure, `variableName = [...]`, so you can iterate over them. I would strongly advise against approach 2, as the code becomes extremely obscure.

Comment: Arguably, if you are the only person who is ever going to maintain this code, you can pretty much do whatever you want. However, if others will have to maintain/change it in the future, it would be better to be explicit when coding it, even if that is repetitive. That's what cut'n'paste and editors are for.

Comment: Having identically named variables that differ with an ending digit is a code smell (`linePrecio1`, `linePrecio2`, `linePrecio3`, `linePrecio4`).  Better to use something like a list or dictionary or object for these things.

Comment: Also, you should probably not worry about performance at this stage. Write maintainable code, and optimise afterwards if you notice it is needed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Those items are PyQt LineEdit widgets in a GUI. Visual here: http://prntscr.com/g6ucz6 they need to have a different name each and this is the easiest way I found so far.

Comment: You're worried about performance of assigning attributes for a GUI?  The performance bottleneck isn't going to be here.

Comment: Since this is the very first time I am working with GUIs, I was expecting some newbie fails. Sorry if this seems like a silly question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code itself looks like badly developed interface, but assuming that you *must* work with it, you can programatically get attributes of objects with [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr)

So, group ids, indexes reference points and attributes and make smth like

```
groups = (1, 2, 3, 4)
attrs = ('Referencia', 'Concepto', 'Cantidad', 'Precio', 'Descuento')
idx = (15, 22, 29, 38)

for group, index in zip(groups, idx):
    for i, attr in enumerate(attrs):
        getattr(self, 'line' + attr + str(i)).setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[i+index]))
```

Regarding overall code quality:

- such naming (with sequential names) is really bad design. If you have sequences - you probably need to store this data in sequence - store `lineReferencia` as list of objects
- you may come to this at some time or you may not, but try to maintain english names for your code - this makes it more readable for wide range of people. Sometime it may become crucial for codebase support

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say that I have no control over the GUI or the way the items are generated, but I must assign them values. I am suppose to just create the logic of an already Qt Created GUI.

Comment: Life is hard :) Just learn from this experience as much as you can

Comment: This is a decent approach, but it will naturally break if the names of the form elements are changed. Also, it might be a good idea to do the `getattr` dance only once to gather, say, a list of dicts of form elements.

Comment: The person in charge for creating the GUI won't change the name of the elements, so I'll take this approach in order to reduce code, although it becomes harder to understand what happens with those items.

Comment: I've seen these schemes come apart too many times. At a later date something will be added/changed/removed and it's then that the code comes apart and not always in an obvious way. Sorry to rain on the parade. I await down votes :)

Answer (score 0):

**The good way: Object Oriented**

Should should create an object line with fields Referncia, Concepto ... and your main class contains a list of lines. This will be as fast as your extended version.

```
Class Line:
    def __init__(self, ......):
         self.referencia = .....

Class Polygon:
    def __init__(self):
         self.lines = ()
         line1 = Line(.......)
         self.lines.append(line1)
         line2 =
```

**The quick way: For interpreted languages**

```
member_names = ("lineReferencia", "lineConcepto", "lineCantidad", "linePrecio", "lineDescuento")
for i in range(4):
   for member_name in member_names:
       text_widdget = self.__dict__["lineReferencia"  + str(i)]
       i_register = 16 + member_names.index(member_name) + 7 * i
       text_widget.setText(utilidades.ensure_its_str(registro[i_register]))
```

Note the use of `self.__dict__` which is a dict containing current object member variables with their names as key.